# How do I include a derived value in my API response

Tags: laravel

So let's just say I have a `date_of_birth` field in my table. I want both date of birth and the derived value of age to be in my API response. my initial thought was to have a user model method return a derived value

my abstract idea is something like this:

```
<?php

class User extends Authenticatable implements JWTSubject
{
 ...
  protected $show = ['age']


  public function age(){
      // show age function
  }
 ...
}
```

is this possible if not is there a better way ?

Comment: There are at least two ways: 1 - using virtual fields; 2 - pre formating response result with formated data across payload.

Comment: Check here: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Appending Values To JSON](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json)

```
class User extends Authenticatable implements JWTSubject
{
 ...
 protected $appends = ['age', 'birth_year'];


  public function age(){
      // show age function
  }
 ...
}
```